# Browser-sync not loading ASP.NET 5 website using proxy

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, browser-sync

Browsersync seems stuck loading the website when run in proxy mode. When using the same config but another website it does work, so it must be something in my local setup but I have been unable to figure out what.

I'm running it on Windows, proxying a ASP.NET 5 application which runs on localhost:5000. Directly navigating towards this location works fine. Trying to hook into the pipeline on ASP.NET's side signals the html is exported over the pipeline but the browser never receives a response and stays pending.

The logging output indicates no difference besides a different session and the obvious proxy url if I run it on another website, where also other sites on localhost seems to work (on IIS).

Configuration used (gulp):

```
gulp.task('browsersync', function () {
    browserSync({
        proxy: 'localhost:5000',
        notify: true,
        open: true,
        logLevel: 'debug'
    });
});
```

Comment: Since I'm only using the browser sync proxy, I can't see why this would be applicable, but adding ws:true to the initialization still shows the same behavior.

Comment: I misunderstood your question

Comment: I have this problem as well, it happens only when I host the app using dnx web. Browser Sync does not hang if I host my app using Ctrl+F5 from visual studio by IIS Express.

Comment: See this issue too, logged issue here: https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/636

Comment: Didn't you forget to add "port: 80" to the browsersync configuration? Not sure if is gonna fix your problem.